# C# SFTP No Such File

Tags: c#, curl, ftp, sftp, ssh.net

I'm using the [SSH.NET library](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) to connect to a remote SFTP server. I'm trying to use very basic code but it's not working

```
using (var client = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
{
    client.Connect();   
    client.ChangeDirectory(@"sftp://server.example.com/other_directory");
}
```

However, this throws an exception saying `No Such File` on the `ChangeDirectory` method.

I tried the same with Curl but got an error saying

> curl: (51) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

However, I added curl's [--insecure](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) argument and everything worked fine.

Could the `--insecure` part be related to why the `SSH.NET` library isn't working or is there another reason? Is there a way to simulate what `--insecure` does in C#?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds to me like `sftp://server.example.com/` is denying you a secure connection. So it may be a configuration issue, and not anything you're doing wrong on the client side.

Comment: I thought that may be the case at first but I'm able to access it via curl and other third party tools on my machine so I figured it would be on my side?

Comment: Capture data using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare results between working and non working applications.  Usually the issue is difference in the html header(s).

Comment: @jdweng Great idea, thanks!

Comment: Fixed it, answer posted below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this issue, it turns out that any of the methods such as ChangeDirectory and UploadFile expect a path relative to the `WorkingDirectory` property. As a result, I fixed my issue by changing it to

```
client.ChangeDirectory(@"/other_directory");
```

Hope that helps someone else

Comment: The `/other_directory` is an absolute path, not relative path. The point is the methods require paths, but you were giving URL instead.

Comment: I thought it's a relative path? It's relative to the working directory http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: That article is wrong. It says "paths", but it's about URLs actually. We talk about paths here, not URLs. A path relative to working directory does cannot start with slash.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was permissions for the user "username".
var client = new SftpClient(host, username, password)

So the user "username" must have necessary permission on the folder other_directory for the following code to work correctly.

```
client.ChangeDirectory(@"/other_directory");
```